# Do we really can get the email information from youtube API

Tags: php, youtube

How I'm trying to learn about YouTube API development. I learn from this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

if we go to one of YouTube channel and go to tab "about". Ex: https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast/about

There have section to display the email information like this
[image]

however when I check the YouTube API. There is no email information display. Here is what I've done using @MrBeast channel handle

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet,brandingSettings,statistics,topicDetails,status&id=UCX6OQ3DkcsbYNE6H8uQQuVA&key=xxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

it returns me this information

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "xon0_e-qWBqsfUHp1Za0szjhB9Q",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "s__JsOJ0SRawwt2DIoa-WR2sddQ",
            "id": "UCX6OQ3DkcsbYNE6H8uQQuVA",
            "snippet": {
                "title": "MrBeast",
                "description": "SUBSCRIBE FOR A COOKIE!\nAccomplishments\n- Raised $20,000,000 To Plant 20,000,000 Trees\n- Given millions to charity\n- Donated over 100 cars lol\n- Gave away a private island\n- Given away over 100 ps4s lol\n- Gave away 1 million dollars in one video \n- Counted to 100k\n- Read the Dictionary\n- Watched Dance Till You're Dead For 10 Hours\n- Read Bee Movie Script\n- Read Longest English Word\n- Watched Paint Dry\n- Ubering Across America\n- Watched It's Every Day Bro For 10 Hours\n- Ran a marathon in the world's largest shoes\n- Adopted every dog in a shelter\nYou get the point haha\n\n\n\n*Do not email me asking for money, I give away money because it makes me happy :)",
                "customUrl": "@mrbeast",
                "publishedAt": "2012-02-20T00:43:50Z",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AGIKgqMP6gHKgB5Vry0KGHKg4PF7gHMKs2XRfQvpXwIXRA=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 88,
                        "height": 88
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AGIKgqMP6gHKgB5Vry0KGHKg4PF7gHMKs2XRfQvpXwIXRA=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 240,
                        "height": 240
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AGIKgqMP6gHKgB5Vry0KGHKg4PF7gHMKs2XRfQvpXwIXRA=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 800,
                        "height": 800
                    }
                },
                "localized": {
                    "title": "MrBeast",
                    "description": "SUBSCRIBE FOR A COOKIE!\nAccomplishments\n- Raised $20,000,000 To Plant 20,000,000 Trees\n- Given millions to charity\n- Donated over 100 cars lol\n- Gave away a private island\n- Given away over 100 ps4s lol\n- Gave away 1 million dollars in one video \n- Counted to 100k\n- Read the Dictionary\n- Watched Dance Till You're Dead For 10 Hours\n- Read Bee Movie Script\n- Read Longest English Word\n- Watched Paint Dry\n- Ubering Across America\n- Watched It's Every Day Bro For 10 Hours\n- Ran a marathon in the world's largest shoes\n- Adopted every dog in a shelter\nYou get the point haha\n\n\n\n*Do not email me asking for money, I give away money because it makes me happy :)"
                },
                "country": "US"
            },
            "statistics": {
                "viewCount": "25812006736",
                "subscriberCount": "152000000",
                "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
                "videoCount": "742"
            },
            "topicDetails": {
                "topicIds": [
                    "/m/019_rr",
                    "/m/07c1v",
                    "/m/02jjt"
                ],
                "topicCategories": [
                    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifestyle_(sociology)",
                    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology",
                    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entertainment"
                ]
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public",
                "isLinked": true,
                "longUploadsStatus": "longUploadsUnspecified",
                "madeForKids": false
            },
            "brandingSettings": {
                "channel": {
                    "title": "MrBeast",
                    "description": "SUBSCRIBE FOR A COOKIE!\nAccomplishments\n- Raised $20,000,000 To Plant 20,000,000 Trees\n- Given millions to charity\n- Donated over 100 cars lol\n- Gave away a private island\n- Given away over 100 ps4s lol\n- Gave away 1 million dollars in one video \n- Counted to 100k\n- Read the Dictionary\n- Watched Dance Till You're Dead For 10 Hours\n- Read Bee Movie Script\n- Read Longest English Word\n- Watched Paint Dry\n- Ubering Across America\n- Watched It's Every Day Bro For 10 Hours\n- Ran a marathon in the world's largest shoes\n- Adopted every dog in a shelter\nYou get the point haha\n\n\n\n*Do not email me asking for money, I give away money because it makes me happy :)",
                    "keywords": "mrbeast6000 beast mrbeast Mr.Beast mr",
                    "unsubscribedTrailer": "1WEAJ-DFkHE",
                    "country": "US"
                },
                "image": {
                    "bannerExternalUrl": "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/NP3nTQ3kxLiXV-kLXKS2zaNL6ESMMBv74m-d5a--q5ThgLD6I-IyqLwAbj-AbClWNbORBg3Pcg"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

there is no information about email address. I also do a research for other API endpoint but the result also negative.

Do we really can get the email information use YouTube API? or maybe there are another way to obtain the email address?

Please help.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76003462).

Comment: yes but not so clear and detail. @BenjaminLoison

Comment: @ferdinand that information is not available through the API.

Comment: so the email only appear on youtube about page, isn't it? @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: do we able to get the email from the channel beside API? i mean other way by code.

Comment: @ferdinand yes. I've read here on Stack Overflow about questions involving this requirement and in most of them, they use Selenium.